# Get web page contents from Firefox in a C# program

Tags: c#, firefox-addon

I need to write a simple C# app that should receive entire contents of a web page currently opened in Firefox. Is there any way to do it directly from C#? If not, is it possible to develop some kind of plug-in that would transfer page contents? As I am a total newbie in Firefox plug-ins programming, I'd really appreciate any info on getting me started quickly. Maybe there are some sources I can use as a reference? Doc links? Recommendations?

**UPD**: I actually need to communicate with a Firefox instance, not get contents of a web page from a given URL

Comment: I'll give you the first part; from C#, a web page can be read using the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx.  I don't know about grabbing a page in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you elaborate What you are trying to achieve. May be plugins already out there such as firebug can help.

Anways, if you really want to develop both plugin and C# application:

Check out this tutorial on firefox extension:
http://robertnyman.com/2009/01/24/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/

Otherwise, You can use WebRequest or HttpWebRequest class in .NET request to get the HTML source of any URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd almost certainly need to write a Firefox plugin for that.  However there are certainly ways to request a webpage, and receive its HTML response within C#.  It depends on what your requirements are?

If you're requirements are simply receive the source from any website, leave a comment and I'll point you towards the code.

Comment: Sorry for the fuzzy question, I clarified it a bit. I need to communicate with a Firefox instance.

Comment: In that case you'll need to go down the Firefox plugin route

Comment: If that is the case, then you need to have a plugin in firefox, which can lets say will write the Url to temp file and C# will read the file and emit the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = new Uri(url); 
System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri.AbsoluteUri);
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 3;
        //req.UserAgent = _UserAgent; //"Mozilla/6.0 (MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; Searcharoo.NET)";
        req.KeepAlive = true;
        req.Timeout = _RequestTimeout * 1000; //prefRequestTimeout 

        // SIMONJONES http://codeproject.com/aspnet/spideroo.asp?msg=1421158#xx1421158xx
        req.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        req.CookieContainer.Add(_CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri));
```

System.Net.HttpWebResponse webresponse = null;

```
        try
        {
            webresponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            webresponse = null;
            Console.Write("request for url failed: {0} {1}", url, ex.Message);
        }

        if (webresponse != null)
        {
            webresponse.Cookies = req.CookieContainer.GetCookies(req.RequestUri);
            // handle cookies (need to do this incase we have any session cookies)
            foreach (System.Net.Cookie retCookie in webresponse.Cookies)
            {
                bool cookieFound = false;
                foreach (System.Net.Cookie oldCookie in _CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri))
                {
                    if (retCookie.Name.Equals(oldCookie.Name))
                    {
                        oldCookie.Value = retCookie.Value;
                        cookieFound = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!cookieFound)
                {
                    _CookieContainer.Add(retCookie);
                }
            }
string enc = "utf-8"; // default
            if (webresponse.ContentEncoding != String.Empty)
            {
                // Use the HttpHeader Content-Type in preference to the one set in META
                doc.Encoding = webresponse.ContentEncoding;
            }
            else if (doc.Encoding == String.Empty)
            {
                doc.Encoding = enc; // default
            }
            //http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Code/2003/Dec/ReadingWebPageSources.asp
            System.IO.StreamReader stream = new System.IO.StreamReader
                (webresponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(doc.Encoding));
```

webresponse.Close();

Comment: Please use the `{}`  button to make your code look like code.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want.

```
using System.Net;

var cli = new WebClient();
string data = cli.DownloadString("http://www.heise.de");
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) enables an extension to exchange messages with a native application installed on the user's computer.